# Random things that actually belong together

Tags: riddle, wordplay

All of these clues are like birds of a feather.
If you get them all right you'll know why they're together.

> 1. Wednesday's Older Relative
> 2. Woody Allen
> 3. A Pigeon Holing
> 4. Cholesterol Meds
> 5. Cohort of Viper
> 6. Someone who just wants "to look good naked!"
> 7. Proctor
> 8. To Persistently Annoy
> 9. Cop Using 'Cuffs
> 10. Termite
> 11. Civil Activist
> 12. NY/MN city
> 13. Between 6 months and Placenta
> 14. Stylin' in the 70's
> 15. Almanac's Regret OR Manacle Garters

No hinting yet...

Comment: 13: third trimester? 1: Uncle Lester?

Comment: 12: how about Rochester?

Comment: Fat fingered a downvote.  Sorry.  @Chowzen, can you please edit the question so I can upvote?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Full answer:

They seem to be

> Words that rhyme with "ester"

Details -

> 1. Wednesday's Older Relative - **Uncle Fester**  (from Addam's Family)
>  2. Woody Allen - **Molester** (some say)
>  3. A Pigeon Holing - **Nester** <s>sequester</s>
>  4. Cholesterol Meds - **Crestor** (not a perfect rhyme)
>  5. Cohort of Viper ?  **Jester**  (from Top Gun)
>  6. Someone who just wants "to look good naked!" **Lester**  (from American Beauty)  per [@Mike M.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2717/mike-m)
>  7. Proctor - **Tester**
>  8. To Persistently Annoy - **Pester**
>  9. Cop Using 'Cuffs - **Arrester**
>  10. Termite - **Infester**
>  11. Civil Activist - **Protester**
>  12. NY/MN city - **Rochester**
>  13. Between 6 months and Placenta - **Third Trimester** per [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)
>  14. Stylin' in the 70's - **Polyester**
>  15. Almanac's Regret OR Manacle Garters - Anagram of "Lecter's Anagram"  - Miss **Hester** Mofet (miss the rest of me)  From *Silence of the Lambs*.  thanks to [@M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) and [@Mike M.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2717/mike-m)